# Why is that in Oracle when we fetch values from an alias we cant able to specify column as aliases?

Tags: sql, oracle

For ex.
My query :

```
select * 
from 
    (SELECT distinct b.lname||' '||b.fname as "Manager",b.EMPID as "Mgrid" 
     from EMPLOYEE1) a, 
    (select lname,fname,empid from EMPLOYEE1) b 
where b.EMPID=a.MGRID)
```

is fetching

```
Manager           Mgrid    
----------------  -------- 
Farooque Umer     104      
Sontireddy Kiran  107      
Chopra Bhupendra  103
```

but I cant write :

```
select Manager, Mgrid 
from 
    (select distinct b.lname||' '||b.fname as "Manager",b.EMPID as "Mgrid" 
    from EMPLOYEE1) a, 
    (select lname,fname,empid 
    from EMPLOYEE1) b 
where b.EMPID=a.MGRID)
```

Error:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-1 --------------------------
>    ORA-00904: "MGRID": invalid identifier

Comment: What if you write `SELECT "Manager"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because as soon as you start enclosing names in double quotes like "Mgrid" they becone case-sensitive.  So don't.  Do this:

```
select Manager, Mgrid 
from 
    (select distinct b.lname||' '||b.fname as Manager,b.EMPID as Mgrid 
    from EMPLOYEE1) a, 
    (select lname,fname,empid 
    from EMPLOYEE1) b 
where b.EMPID=a.MGRID)
```

or if you really like case-sensitive names you must do this:

```
select "Manager", "Mgrid" 
from 
    (select distinct b.lname||' '||b.fname as "Manager",b.EMPID as "Mgrid" 
    from EMPLOYEE1) a, 
    (select lname,fname,empid 
    from EMPLOYEE1) b 
where b.EMPID=a."Mgrid")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only apply cosmetic field naming at the top level select - all other identifiers should be kept as valid Oracle identifiers.

```
select manager as "Manager", mgrid as "Mgrid" 
from 
    (select distinct b.lname||' '||b.fname as manager, b.EMPID as mgrid
    from EMPLOYEE1) a, 
    (select lname,fname,empid 
    from EMPLOYEE1) b 
where b.EMPID=a.MGRID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the quotes, I think your post contains one more parenthesis than needed:

```
select Manager, Mgrid 
from 
    (select distinct b.lname||' '||b.fname as Manager,b.EMPID as Mgrid 
    from EMPLOYEE1 a, 
    (select lname,fname,empid 
    from EMPLOYEE1) b 
    where b.empid =a.Mgrid)
```

Comment: This will not keep the case - the result will show the fields as MANAGER and MGRID. The quotes preserve the case.

Comment: The paranthesis would have been my fault when reformatting the code!